# How to Assign 1 value to variables(more than 2 variable) at once

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, variable-assignment

Can we assign  1 value to variables(more than 2 variable) at once in VB.net
like this :

```
dim a,b,c,d,e,f,g as string = "A Character"
```

i can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: no, u cant do that at declaration level

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: in vb.net there is no way to assign a value to multiple variables in a single command.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need that to be in one line

```
Dim aChar As String = "MyString"
Dim a, b, c, d As String
a = aChar : b = aChar : c = aChar : d = aChar
```

Comment: Thanks @bansi, I just know about this

Comment: +1 - this works but it is just putting four lines onto one line (@bansi - I think your statement is incorrect)

Comment: @MattWilko I wrote that comment when the answer was `a = b = c = d = e = f = g = aChar`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this if you want separate variable names but you can if you use some sort of `Array` or `List` to hold your variables.

The following generates a `List(Of String)` that contains 5 string elements, each element is holds the value `"foo"`

```
 Dim s = Enumerable.Repeat("foo", 5).ToList
```